# Can't connect to Jenkins Slave No Known Hosts file was found at /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts

Tags: jenkins

Here are my jenkins config:[image]

[image]

Error message:

```
/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts [SSH] No Known Hosts file was found at /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts. Please ensure one is created at this path and that Jenkins can read it.
```

No matter how much I tried it doesn't work. I've read [this post](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42959), but still no solution.

Comment: That error isn't saying there is a missing entry in the hosts file, it's saying that there is no host file. can you confirm that a file even exists at that location?

Comment: no host file there. How can I add a host file? What should be in the host file?

Comment: the host file is the file about which Jenkins is complaining: `.ssh/known_hosts`. That file needs to contain an entry for the slave machine. The easiest way to accomplish this is by sshing yourself from the Jenkins master into the slave machine as `jenkins` user). That, by the way, will serve as a verification of whether this kind of connection works first of all

Answer (score 43):

I got the same error while launching slave.It has to do with the `SSH Slave Plugin`. What worked for me was changing the  Host key verification strategy in LAUNCH METHOD from "`Known Hosts file verification strategy`" to `"Manually trusted key verification strategy"`.

> CONFIGURE AGENT -> LAUNCH METHOD -> Manually trusted key verification
>   strategy - > SAVE.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that Jenkins causes confusion by reporting that the file is missing under `/var/jenkins_home/`, which is a hard-coded value. Instead, it should be telling you that the file is missing under your actual `$JENKINS_HOME` path. That way, you would immediately know where to look.

So the easiest way to fix this is to:

1. Go to the actual `$JENKINS_HOME` directory on your Jenkins master, and create a `.ssh` directory and `known_hosts` file under it, for example:

   ```
   $ mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh
   $ touch $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
   ```
2. If you've ever SSH-ed from Jenkins master to your slave machine before, then you should already have a `known_hosts` file under your `~/.ssh` directory. If you don't, then SSH from Jenkins master to Jenkins slave machine and it will get automatically created for you under `~/.ssh` directory for that user.
3. Now open that `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and simply copy>paste the line that contains your slave machine's IP address to the `$JENKINS_HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Alternative way is to copy the entire `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file to `$JENKINS_HOME/.ssh` directory if that is easier for you.

Comment: Hi, how do you ssh into a slave/agent machine in order to get a `known_hosts` file?

Answer (score -3):

A very simple step helped me to recover this error.

In Slave configuration, select "No verifying verification strategy" for Host Key Verification Strategy. This will allow master to connect with slave and host will also be remembered.

Next time on selecting "Known host file verification strategy" will not give this error.

Comment: Using "No verifying verification strategy" is strongly discouraged. A better solution is populating the master's `known_hosts`. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42959